# mvc get virtual IEnumerable from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind a `dropdownlistfor` to a list that comes from the database

In the model

```
public class Actor
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    ...

    // I have a database table called genre
    [ForeignKey("Genre")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

}
```

In the controller

```
    // GET: Actors/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Actor actor = new Actor();

        actor.Genres = new // Believe I need to do something here...
        return View(actor);
    }
```

In the view

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genres, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Value", "Text"))
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What is it i need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create ViewModel for this

```
public class ActorViewModel
{
    public Actor actor { get; set; }
    public SelectList Genres { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
}
```

Create a method that returns the genres as a selectlist

```
 public SelectList GetAsSelectList()
    {
        var genres = (from s in GetAllGenres()
                        select new
                        {
                            s.Id, s.Name
                        }).ToList();
        return new SelectList((IEnumerable)genres, "Id", "Name");
    }
```

In your controller you populate the model properties:

```
var model = new ActorViewModel
{
    actor = new Actor(),
    Genres = GetAsSelectList(),
    GenreId = 0
};
return View(model);
```

In the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.GenreId, Model.Genres,"--Select--")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would usually add a property to my `ViewModel` that is of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`:

```
public class ActorViewModel
{
     public int GenreId { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my `Controller` I would add a method that will return these for you:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGenres() 
{
     foreach (var genre in dbContext.Genres)
     {
          yield return new SelectListItem 
              {
                  Value = genre.Id.ToString(),
                  Text = genre.Name
              };
     }
}
```

Then set as so:

```
viewModel.Genres = this.GetGenres();
```

Then in my `View`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GenreId, Model.Genres, "Please select")
```